# cmake: pregenerate Makefile for non-existing sources

Tags: makefile, cmake

My program generates c++ code which needs to be compiled into a dynamic library.
The code is generated in some directory, the name of it is unknown before generating a Makefile (the directories are created in runtime), but the names of the files the library depend on are predefined (src1.cpp, src2.cpp ..).
Is there any way to generate a Makefile using cmake so that it could be copied into a directory with sources of the library that need to be compiled.
I've tried to add_library which is dependent on src1.cpp src2.cpp .. , but cmake doesn't want to generate a Makefile without having the sources available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your use-case, but I think you could probably set the [`GENERATED`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/prop_sf/GENERATED.html) property to `TRUE` for each non-existent file to fix this.  e.g. say your list of files is `MyFiles`, you can use [`set_source_files_properties`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/set_source_files_properties.html):

```
set_source_files_properties(${MyFiles} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
```

You might also have to create dependencies to ensure these files actually exist before make tries to build the library (e.g. if they're generated by a script, have the script invoked as a pre-build command of the library using [`add_custom_command(TARGET MyLib PRE_BUILD ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/add_custom_command.html)).